$(4{\log_2}^2 x + \log_2x - 5)\sqrt{7^x - m} = 0.$ Find all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the given equation has precisely $2$ distinct solutions.

Consider the equation $(4{\log_2}^2 x + \log_2x - 5)\sqrt{7^x - m} = 0.$ How  many positive values of $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the given equation has precisely $2$ distinct solutions.

After some refinement, I was able to solve the problem. However, my solution seems quite lengthy, which could be problematic as this is a multiple-choice question in an exam with a tight time constraint, so refined thinking is crucial. It also took me several attempts before I finally arrived at the correct answer. I was hoping to get some feedback on my thought process and potentially learn from more efficient solutions. Thank you very much!
My solution:
$(4{\log_2}^2 x + \log_2x - 5)\sqrt{7^x - m} = 0 \quad (*)$
Condition 1: $x > 0$
Condition 2: $7^x - m \geq 0$
$(*) \iff \log_2x = 1 \lor \log_2x = -\frac54 \lor 7^x - m = 0 \iff  x = 2 \lor x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}} \lor x = \log_7m$
The original equation has exactly $2$ distinct solutions in the following scenarios:
Case 1: $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ satisfy the conditions, while $x = \log_7m$ does not.
This happens when $\log_7m \leq 0 \implies m \leq 1 \implies m = 1.$ Both $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ satisfy condition 1 and condition 2 with $m = 1$, so $m = 1$ works.
Case 2: $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ satifisfy the conditions, while $x = \log_7m$ also satisfies the conditions and is equal to either $2$ or $2^{-\frac{5}{4}}.$
This happens when $\log_7m = 2$ or $\log_7m = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}} \iff m = 7^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $m = 7^{2^{-\frac54}} \notin \mathbb{Z}.$ So $m = 49.$
Since $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ satisfy condition 1, we check condition 2 for both values with $m = 49.$ It's clear that $7^{2^{-\frac54}} - 49 < 0,$ so $m = 49$ does not work and thus this case is not possible.
Case 3: One of $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ does not satisfy the conditions, while $x = \log_7m$ satisfies the conditions and is distinct from the other solution.
Since both $x = 2$ and $x = 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ satisfy condition 1, one of them must not satisfy condition 2.
Condition 2 is $7^x - m \geq 0 \iff x \geq \log_7m.$
Since $2 > 2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ and only one of them does not satisfy condition 2, the one that does not satisfy the condition must be $x =2^{-\frac{5}{4}}.$
$\implies 2^{-\frac{5}{4}} < \log_7m \leq 2 \iff  2.6 < m \leq 49 \iff m \in \{3, 4, 5, ..., 48, 49\}.$
$x = \log_7m$ already satisfies condition 2, and for each $m$ in the above set, $m > 1$, so $x = \log_7m > 0,$ satisfying condition 1.
However, $x = \log_7m$ must be distinct from the other solution, which is $2,$ so $m = 49$ does not work.
Combining all three cases, we have that $m \in \{1, 3, 4, 5,...,48\},$ so there are $47$ possible values of $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the original equation has precisely $2$ distinct solutions.

Instead of dividing conditions over $x$, divide them in $m$. Obviously, $m\le 0$ is one set of valid solutions. Therefore, we henceforth assume $m\ge 1$.
The roots of $4{\log_2}^2 x + \log_2x - 5=0$ are $2$ and $2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$. The root of $\sqrt{7^x-m}=0$ is $\log_7m$. For $m\ge 49$, the only root of the equation is $\log_7m$. Therefore $m\le 48$. For $m= 2$, we have all possible three roots: $2$, $2^{-\frac{5}{4}}$ and $\log_72$. For $m=1$, the solution of $7^x-m=0$ is $x=0$, which is not a valid solution for the equation in general, since every such solution must be positive. We therefore end up with two distinct solutions at $m=1$. Therefore, the final solution is
$
\Bbb Z^{\le 1}\cup \{n\in\Bbb Z:3\le n\le 48\}.
$

Hi, thank you very much! I have a few questions.


It seems you missed the part that requires $m > 0?$ Even so, for $m < 0,$ it seems we always have three solutions, but the question requires we find $m$ such that the equation has exactly $2$ solutions, so I believe $m <0$ would not work either way?


For $m = 1,$ $x = \log_7m = 0$ can't be a solution as $x$ must be greater than $0,$ so in this case, we have $2$ solutions instead of $3$ solutions, so $m = 1$ should work, right?



In the case of $m=1$, I agree with you and I will edit my response to cover that. In the case of $m<0$, the $7^x-m=0$ does not have any solutions (in real numbers). For example, consider $7^x+1=0$.

My bad! You're completely right that for $m < 0,$ $7^x - m= 0$ does not have any solution. Thank you very much!

That' fair. One mistake each :)
